# Wine 1.5 Error Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wine, flash

I installed a program with Wine 1.5, but when I try to open it I get the following error
[image]

The program (A2J Author) is a program written in flash. Do I need to install Flash using Wine as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to install Flash using Wine as well?

Yes, your program requires the Flash ActiveX (ocx) component, so you will have to install it within Wine as well.

---

In general, if a program running under Wine requires anything beyond the basic (built-in) Windows libraries, which are provided by Wine itself, you will need to download and install them separately under Wine. This includes Java, .NET, Flash, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I installed [Download the Windows Flash Player 11.2 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE)](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#fp11) and it works great now.